# Mesh deformed/not moving properly

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, weight-painting

I'm rather novice. I would like to animate this letter "T" as though it's a human whereby the horizontal line on the "T" acts like the arms. I want the "T" to have its arm down by its side but it's deformed when I tried. I have done the weight paint as well as through the edit Vertex Group but it still doesn't work. [Here's my blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AafWHyFmXwEmLNH-YOAhrdUjz4czGPai/view?usp=sharing). Can someone please help?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try subdividing the mesh around 5 times. At the moment you don't have enogh geometry to create a smooth result. In Edit mode, select All then right-click > Subdivide and increase the subdivisions to 5 in the bottom-left panel ... and as @moonboots says recalculate the normals!

Answer (score 0):

As you can see if you enable the *Face Orientation* display option, your face normals are flipped. So go in *Edit* mode, select all and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate, then parent again and it should work correctly.

[image]

Comment: Hello, wow it worked way better. However there are some creases at the "under arm"  Do you know how to fix that?